# Render table in Vue template

Tags: vue.js, html-table, v-for

I am trying to render a table from an object with header and body data:

```
const mydata = {header: {}, body: {}}
```

This produces two `<table>` elements:

```
<template>
  <div class="container" id="ProbabilityTable">
    <div id="v-for-object">
      <table>
        <div v-for="(data, key) in table(html)">

          <thead v-if="key === 'header'">
            // render table header
          </thead>

          <tbody v-if="key === 'body'">          
            // render table body
          </tbody>

        </div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

were as this:

```
<template>
  <div class="container" id="ProbabilityTable">
    <div id="v-for-object">
      <table>
        <div v-for="(data, key) in table(html)">

          <thead v-if="key === 'header'">
            // render table header
          </thead>
          <tbody v-if="key === 'body'">          
            // render body header
          </tbody>

        </div>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

produces one table which is broken because there html tables should not have divs in the middle of them.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<template></template>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt) tag.

`<template>` tag doesn't render itself as an element, but you can use it for conditions and loops in vue.

```
<template>
<div class="container" id="ProbabilityTable">
   <div id="v-for-object">
     <table>
      <template v-for="(data, key) in table(html)">
        <thead v-if="key === 'header'">
        // render table header
        </thead>
        <tbody v-if="key === 'body'">          
        // render body header
        </tbody>
      </template>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Also for nested loops the template element is the way to go unfortunately I can only have max 3 nested loops with the template element in a table while in unordered list I can loop more then 3 times. Any idea why that is? ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184054/nested-loops-in-table-with-template-element-gives-memory-error

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop for your header and your body separate then you don't need to make an extra div or template.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr v-for="(row, headerKey) in table(html).header" :key="headerKey">
      <td>{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, bodyKey) in table(html).body" :key="bodyKey">
      <td>{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

The 2 snippets you posted are interpreted the same. And both of them are wrong.

As stated here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table divs are not a valid content for tables. And because of this, every browser will interpret the error differently.

**Solution:** use valid HTML syntax and see if the problem persists.

Comment: As I did say I know that divs in a table are wrong, but how do I get the template to work using correct syntax? There must be some sort of workaround while "using valid HTML syntax"